# How to make $fh = fopen change file name every day according to date

Tags: php, file, date, get, line

Hi my problem is I got a server and I want admins to be able to look into my server logs
I can use this:

```
$fh = fopen('F:\web\Chat2014-07-07.log','r');
```

But this will load the file from the day and I will have to do that every morning or evening. is there any way how change it's name automatically every day ?

I appreciate any tips it would be very usefull..

Comment: You have a new log every day? How about `$date = date('Y-m-d'); fopen("F:\web\Chat$date.log",'r');`?

Comment: yes today's is "Chat2014-07-08.log" and so on it goes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as mentioned in my comment, you can just stick a variable in there with todays date:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d'); 
$fh = fopen("F:\web\Chat$date.log",'r');
```

That will (today) open a file called "Chat2014-07-08.log"

Comment: Please not...... use `fopen('F:\web\Chat' . $date . '.log','r');` watch out for escape character and variable in quotes.

Comment: @DanFromGermany This will work just fine; I prefer `sprintf()`, though ;-)

Comment: ok thanks a lot people it works great ! exept i cant use numbers for example `$fh = fopen("F:\web\1.Server\Chat$date.log",'r');`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
$fh = fopen('F:\web\Chat'.date('Y-m-d').'.log','r');
```

Answer (score 0):

U can try in this way

// Change the line below to your timezone!

date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne');

$todaysDate = date('Y-m-d');

$fh = fopen('F:\web\Chat{$todaysDate}.log','r');